# Android - Hebrew locale doesn't work in Samsung S1

Tags: android, localization

I'm need to show date in dd/MM/yyyy format (full month name) in Hebrew.
In Samsung s1 - it shows me English locale and in Motorola Atrix 4G it works fine 
(shows the month name in Hebrew).
I'm using:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, getLocale());

// I TRIED ALL THESE 3 LOCALES
private Locale getLocale() {
    return new Locale("he");
    //return new Locale("iw_IL");
    //return new Locale("iw");
}
```

Note: I need to show Hebrew even if the phone defalt locale is different.

How can I implement for all devices (that has hebrew)?

Comment: what version of android do you run?

Comment: I'm using 2.3.3 for Samsung S1 and Motorola Atrix

Comment: if your phone doesn't know hebrew, i don't see how you can have it display months in hebrew. unless these are in your app resource ?

Comment: then i'd set it in hebrew in the settings, not in the app. (or, first set it in the settings, then check the current locale in the app)

Comment: For what I know Hebrew local is a whole lot of trouble, had an issue with it when I was trying to get addresses in Hebrew was giving me different result where some were in English and some in Hebrew. I think you should pass this up.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Google](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html), `en_US ... is the only locale Java guarantees is always available.`

If you know you're going to need Hebrew month names regardless of what's provided by the underlying platform, you should include that data in your app.

Comment: I don't have a Galaxy S so I cannot directly confirm or deny that it includes Hebrew.  The Android 4.2 emulator does not include a Hebrew locale, so it is clearly not universal.  Google, in the official documentation, clearly states that only en_US is guaranteed.  Therefore if you want to "implement for all devices" you will need to do it yourself.

Comment: The code you have should work fine on all devices that support Hebrew.  According to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10022/how-to-install-hebrew-on-a-samsung-galaxy-s-vibrant and http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=734389, the Galaxy S does not come with Hebrew support.